# Two different types, one method implementation in C#

Tags: c#

What would be best approach to implement this scenario:
There is service method and two types, which differs only on List items type:

```
public long MyMethod(MyType request) {...}
```

Also i have two models, which are almost similar:

```
public class MyType {
    public int amount {get; set;}
    public List<MyDetailsType> details {get; set;}
}

public class MyType2 {
    public int amount {get; set;}
    public List<MyDetailsType2> details {get; set;}
}
```

How to make this one method

```
public long MyMethod(MyType request) {...}
```

work for both request types without **overload**? Interface? Abstract class? Virtual?
Also the method is called once, so generic type not work, because method need parameter type defined, which i dont know until variable not set.

App flow is as follows:

- Get request
- Request is generated by some conditions to MyType or MyType2
- Call to MyMethod

```
Method1(SomeType request) {
    var request;
    if(a) {
       request = new MyType();
    } else {
       request = new MyType2();
    }

    MyMethod(request);
}
```

Comment: Depending on the involved operations, another option might be to make `MyType` generic: `public class MyType<T> { ... List<T> details; }`

Comment: Yes, my first approach was like this, but when were creating:
MyTypeAbstract someRequest;
if(someLogic){ someRequest = new MyType() }else{ someRequest = new MyType2()}
this looked not ok, when not all child object properties was on this variable, because its type is abstract class type.

Comment: Klaus - how to use it in that method then? It is implemented via interface. I need to provide parameter type for it. And call of method also one.

Comment: `public long MyMethod<T>(MyType<T> request) {...}`

Comment: Therefore I wrote "depending on the involved operations". For a more definite answer, we would need to know what you are doing with MyType.

Comment: [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info)

Comment: that's excactly what generics are used for.

Comment: Do you need to assign it to the same variable variable in both branches? Or would `if(a) { MyMethod(new MyType()); } else { MyMethod(new MyType2()); }` work?

Comment: No, there will be to much logic in there. I want to set request by some logic and then call service method.

Comment: You've not given any information why just doing `object MyMethod1(SomeType request)` and then `public long MyMethod(object request)` wouldn't work. You need to specify what parts of `MyType`/`MyType2` are used in `MyMethod`. This whole thing depends on the required common functionality and the reasoning why you decided to make `Method1` the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```cs
public long MyMethod<T>(MyBaseType<T> request) { ... }

public abstract class MyBaseType<T>
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public List<T> Details { get; set; }
}

public class MyType : MyBaseType<MyDetailsType>
{
    // additional code
}

public class MyType2 : MyBaseType<MyDetailsType2>
{
    // additional code
}
```

---

***If no additional code is needed*** for the derived classes, you can just use one class (without the `abstract` keyword).

The `Method1` code would look something like this:

```cs
void Method1(SomeType request)
{
    if (a)
       request = new MyBaseType<MyDetailsType>();
    else
       request = new MyBaseType<MyDetailsType2>();

    MyMethod(request);
}
```

Comment: What if no additional code is needed then?
Those are model classes, and differs only by Details type?

Comment: And then there is a problem when assigning variable in if, because when initializing it, it needs type

Comment: `var request` this is not a valid statement. But I really feel OP needs to provide more information and background before we can even begin giving good solutions to the problem.

Comment: Will not work var, VS asks proper type and i dont know it before if.

Comment: @rokask what's the method signature for Method1()?